# Mount a MicroSD to all namespaces on Android 11

Tags: file-system, linux, mount, magisk, systemless-root

I'm trying to mount a MicroSD. As I understand it, this should be done in the global namespace. Root - Magisk.

I tried:

- `su --mm -c mount -t sdfat /dev/block/mmcblk0p1 /storage/0123-4567`
- `nsenter -t 1 -m mount -t sdfat /dev/block/mmcblk0p1 /storage/0123-4567`

As a result, the root namespace is mounted, but nothing is mounted in other applications. How to mount to all namespaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it.
In my case, it was necessary to go into the mount namespace of the systems process at number 104.

```
nsenter -t 104 -m mount -t sdfat /dev/block/mmcblk0p1 /storage/0123-4567
```